# 'firebase' is not defined no-undef error, I cannot get this to work

Tags: reactjs, firebase

No matter what I do, I always get the same result when trying to import Firebase Auth in React. As someone who is new to React, I am finding it difficult to figure out what the problem is and how to fix it. Despite my best efforts to try different importing methods, I am still getting the same output every time. It's frustrating because I want to be able to move forward with my project, but this roadblock is slowing me down.

Error

```
./src/components/Register.js
  Line 13:  'firebase' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Register.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { auth } from '../firebase';


const Register = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const handleRegister = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      setEmail('');
      setPassword('');
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    }
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Register</h1>
      {error && <p>{error}</p>}
      <form onSubmit={handleRegister}>
        <input
          type="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

const firebaseConfig = {
  //project settings
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { auth, db, storage };


if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

const firestoreNamespace = firebase.firestore

export {firebase, firestoreNamespace};
```

I've tried changing the `import { auth } from '../firebase';` around but no help. I'm using node 16.10 if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to help you exactly but in my project with firebase my firebase.json file looks like this:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  addDoc,
  deleteDoc,
  serverTimestamp,
  doc,
  orderBy,
  limit,
  onSnapshot,
  query,
} from 'firebase/firestore';
import {
  getAuth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  updateProfile,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
} from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyALfduQtADUHxMaELFidGT7aNaMcLs-SVo",
  authDomain: "tshirtsnew-a3e97.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "tshirtsnew-a3e97",
  storageBucket: "tshirtsnew-a3e97.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1020435418086",
  appId: "1:1020435418086:web:babd9ffdecb42a2a73e427",
  measurementId: "G-JZS9MSJX16"
};

// init firebase app
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// init services
const db = getFirestore();
const auth = getAuth();

export {
  db,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  addDoc,
  deleteDoc,
  serverTimestamp,
  doc,
  auth,
  orderBy,
  limit,
  onSnapshot,
  query,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  updateProfile,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
};
```

And for authorization I used this:

```
https://blog.gmagnenat.co/user-authentication-and-persistence-firebase-9-react-redux-toolkit
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared firebase but you have not imported it hence why you are getting undefined.

But I noticed you are using firebase v9 so you should not be using namespaces, instead you should use modular imports. Check the code below.

```
//Register.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const Register = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const auth = getAuth();

  const handleRegister = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      setEmail('');
      setPassword('');
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    }
  };
 ...
```

In your firebase.js file, i have removed the code after export since you have already initialized firebase.

```
//firebase.js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

const firebaseConfig = {
  //project settings
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { auth, db, storage };
```

Check [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth) for more information.

Comment: cheers your code does work, but when i try to do the same thing with my login.js:
''''
//import react
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const auth = getAuth();

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //try and catch error
    }
  };
//return html code
''''

Comment: It just slap me with this error 
''''
Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options).
▶ 3 stack frames were collapsed.
Login
E:/Programming/hsinfohs/src/components/Login.js:9
   6 |  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
   7 |  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
   8 |  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
>  9 |  const auth = getAuth();
     | ^  10 | 
  11 |  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
  12 |    e.preventDefault();
''''

Comment: Please edit your question to show the full code in login.js file, to make it more readable.

Comment: it give the same error for my register.js too, something to to with the const auth = getAuth();

Comment: Inorder to find out what the issue is with your code, you will need to edit your question with the login.js file.